# No ADB devices found on Chrome Inspect even if they are shown by adb devices

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, adb, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug my Ionic v1 app on Chrome and I cannot find how to make them appear. I was able to do so in the past but it is not working anymore. The device is successfully connected to ADB and shown when using `adb devices` however, Chrome Dev Tools is not showing them. I have tried with two devices and the emulator and none seem to work. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: close all *Chrome* instances then do `adb kill-server` then try *Chrome Inspect* again

Comment: make sure you are not trying to inspect a production build app. You can't.

Comment: It is not production. Now I cannot even start the adb server. I am on mac by the way.